# MFC CListCtrl updating text of any cell

Tags: mfc, clistctrl

This question is to understand how to update any row programatically.
     Details.
     I have a listcrtl, that accepts the data from either from a file or from the edit controls in the dialog. When the items are added I will know its position, that I added, so I can change its subitem texts. I have even implemented the sort functionality in the list, so now the position keeps changing. I have an identifier column for each row, so that I can recognize the row.
     Now, from an out side event, if I have to change an other columns value of an ID that I know , I have to first find the position of the item by comparing the id column, then with that position, I have set the subitemtext.

This works fine except that it takes time to find the row first then it need to update the column.

Now, in order to get the row directly, I need some help.
I have gone through 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh298346(v=vs.85).aspx 
     But this does not use MFC. Please help me achieving this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have many items you should consider switching to [Virtual Lists](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7891/Using-virtual-lists). It is the fastest way to access the data. If you do not want to invest time to this, then the easiest way for you will be the following:

1. When you populate the CListCtrl store the ID of each item in the item data using the SetItemData() method. The ID will always be associated with the item, even after re-sorting.
2. When you need to locate the required item, just scan all items, but do not use GetItemText(). Use GetItemData() instead. This will be faster

Comment: Until now, I do not have many items, so that I have to use virtual list. So, I am just wondering, if there is way to keep track of the items, like keeping a map of pointers to each list item, so that, even though the position changes, still the pointer can be accessed to get the item. But that showed some limitations. Other approach was to keep a map for all those ids and repopulate the map upon sort. Looks like that one is working. However, if we have a direct list item access, that will help a lot.

Comment: @Naresh: If you need direct access to your items through a pointer you should use a virtual list box. Although virtual list boxes are mainly there for performance reasons, performance isn't the only factor in deciding when to use them.